# Collection view datasource methods not recognised

Tags: swift

I changed the type of my controller from a collection view controller to a view controller and now the collection view datasource methods aren't recognised.

I replaced the collection view controller in my storyboard with the new view controller. I then added a collection view to the view controller. I controller dragged the collection view to set it as an outlet. I set the delegate and datasources.

I added the protocols with the class definition:

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
```

I get the error `"Method does not override any method from its superclass."` on the line:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to add `override` if your class implementing the `protocol` methods.Use `override` when you are overriding the methods of superclass.

**Remove the** `override` keyword from the definition.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```