# Changing textview color in chat bubble

Tags: swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to change messages text color in bubbles, I've found it easy in ObjC example, tried to do the same at swift but failed, any solutions?

Here's the ObjC code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  Override point for customizing cells
     */
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    /**
     *  Configure almost *anything* on the cell
     *
     *  Text colors, label text, label colors, etc.
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT set `cell.textView.font` !
     *  Instead, you need to set `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.messageBubbleFont` to the font you want in `viewDidLoad`
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT manipulate cell layout information!
     *  Instead, override the properties you want on `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` from `viewDidLoad`
     */

    JSQMessage *msg = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if (!msg.isMediaMessage) {

        if ([msg.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : cell.textView.textColor,
                                              NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) };
    }
    cell.accessoryButton.hidden = ![self shouldShowAccessoryButtonForMessage:msg];

    return cell;
}**
```

My swift trial 
[image: Swift version]

After editing it to `collectionview` with override as it required, it crashes again

[image]

Comment: post your swift code which you have tried and not working.

Comment: same code translated to swift, it won't work

Comment: @AbdoelrhmanMohamed You need to show us what you have try and what is not working, show us the screenshot of it.

Comment: added  as a screenshot @NiravD

Comment: @AbdoelrhmanMohamed Remove the `override` from the method.

Comment: Yes its the issue .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collection view datasource methods not recognised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730108/collection-view-datasource-methods-not-recognised)

Comment: by removing override it works, but it never gets called!

Comment: @AbdoelrhmanMohamed Can you add more code, add all the method of collectionView.

Comment: added it, got an error as it doesn't cast to jsqcell

Comment: Try like `let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell`

Comment: Finally! thank you! @NiravD

Comment: yes, why not, post the full function if you have it too

Comment: @AbdoelrhmanMohamed I have posted answer if you think it needs edit to be edited feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 4):

From the Objective c code that you have posted above you need to create `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell` instance using `super.collectionView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, so try like this.

```
let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
```

full solution:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

        // messages to show
        let msg = incomingMessages[indexPath.row]

        if !msg.isMediaMessage {
            if msg.senderId! == senderId {
                cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.white
            }else{
                cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.black
            }
            cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: cell.textView.textColor ?? UIColor.white]
        }
        return cell 
    }
```